# Let $\alpha , \beta \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$. Prove that $\alpha$ is a unit $\iff N(\alpha) = 1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, normed-spaces

Where $N(\alpha)$ is the norm of alpha.
I have proved in a previous question that $N(\alpha\beta) = N(\alpha)N(\beta)$. and I have no trouble proving the $\Rightarrow$ but I don't know how to prove the other direction where we start by assuming $N(\alpha) = 1$. 
The norm of an element alpha (= $a + b\sqrt{d}$) is: $N(a + b\sqrt{d}) = |{a^2 - db^2}|$.There is a similar question to mine but it only deals with the direction I have already proved.

Comment: How do you define $N(\alpha)?$ Because the most common way has that $\alpha$ is trivially a divisor of $N(\alpha).$

Comment: If $N(\alpha) = \lvert \prod_{\sigma} \sigma(\alpha) \rvert$, where $\sigma$ ranges over the automorphisms, then this is kind of obvious.

Another way is $N(\alpha) = \lvert det(T_\alpha) \rvert$, where $T_\alpha(x) := \alpha x$ and we see $x$ as an element of the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. Then this follows easily.

Last but not least we could define $N(\alpha) := \lvert \mathcal{O} / (\alpha) \rvert$. Again, this follows easily.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi That link proves the direction the asker doesn't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\;N(\alpha:=a+b\sqrt d)=1\;$ , then

$$(a+b\sqrt d)(a-b\sqrt d)=a^2-b^2d=\pm1=\pm N(\alpha)\implies\alpha\;\text{is a unit} $$

This is basically the same as ajotatxe's answer, but as you haven't yet accepted that answer I added this way to show.

Comment: Thank you I understand now :) !

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac1{a+b\sqrt d}=\frac{a-b\sqrt d}{a^2-b^2d}=\frac{a-b\sqrt d}1$$

Comment: I'm assuming that OP's norm is the absolute value of this norm, or you'd need in the theorem that $N(\alpha)=\pm1$...

Comment: I don't quite understand your proof. How does it show that $\alpha$ which can be written as $a + b\sqrt{d}$ is a unit?